# Brightness is reset to Maximum on every Restart in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, upgrade, brightness

I have upgraded from 13.04 to 13.10. After every reboot the brightness is set to maximum. Is there any solution?

Comment: would you go to settings manager -> additional settings and see the graphics drivers listed there?

Answer (score 0):

Download the master branch of Brightness Controller from [GitHub](https://github.com/lordamit/Brightness/tree/master) as a .zip file.

1. Now extract the downloaded zip file.
2. Head on to `/src` folder.
3. Open a Terminal
4. Run `python path/to/brightness.py`

Now you can control your brightness using your mouse.

[image: pic]

*This was submitted to Ubuntu Software Center but still hasn't been approved for Ubuntu 13.10. We will also make a .deb package soon. An older version of Brightness Controller is available in its [website](http://lordamit.github.io/Brightness/) in Debain package format.*